# Which action should i register in Roslyn to catch ObjectCreation?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Which action should i register in Roslyn to catch ObjectCreation ? I want to catch if coder creates SqlCommand object to do some sql stuff.

P.S. I am new with Roslyn, please be patient i am learning and will be better.

Comment: Have you tried using the Syntax Visualizer tool? It should allow you to analyze existing sources and see exactly what a constructor call looks like: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Syntax%20Visualizer

Comment: `ObjectCreationExpression` seems rather fitting.